# There is a 4-second sound and the next 8 seconds are lost and repeated

Tags: ffmpeg

I have a video. but i want that the 4 first seconds have audio and the next 8 second is muted .and repeat it til the end of the video

For example: There is a 30-second video, the first 4 seconds have audio, 4 - 12 seconds is muted, 12-16 have audio, 16-24 is muted, so the video ends

Please help me finish it thank you

Comment: Requirment is unclear. What does 'negative' mean?

Comment: I have a video. but i want that the 4 first seconds have audio and the next 8 second is muted .and repeat it til the end of the video

Comment: @GyanI have a video. but i want that the 4 first seconds have audio and the next 8 second is muted .and repeat it til the end of the video

Comment: @Gyan sorry i corrected the question again

Comment: @KamilMaciorowski I tried -af "aselect='lt(mod(t,11),4)''

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basic command form is

```
ffmpeg -i in -af volume=0:enable='gte(mod(t\,12)\,4)' out
```

Comment: Why do I see 8 seconds have audio, and 4 seconds is muted , I want it to be the opposite . 8 seconds ismute, and 4 seconds have audio

Comment: Corrected expr.

Comment: I'm sorry . I forgot it, thank you very much

Comment: please help me . I have a logo. I want to move to 4 different positions every 4 minutes, repeating to the end, because I specify the location

Comment: @Monso You should make a new, separate post for each new question.